# Docstrings vs Comments

Tags: python, comments, docstring

I'm a bit confused over the difference between docstrings and comments in python.

In my class my teacher introduced something known as a 'design recipe', a set of steps that will supposedly help us students plot and organize our coding better in Python. From what I understand, the below is an example of the steps we follow - this so call design recipe (the stuff in the quotations):

```
def term_work_mark(a0_mark, a1_mark, a2_mark, ex_mark, midterm_mark):

    ''' (float, float, float, float, float) -> float

    Takes your marks on a0_mark, a1_mark, a2_mark, ex_mark and midterm_mark, 
    calculates their respective weight contributions and sums these 
    contributions to deliver your overall term mark out of a maximum of 55 (This
    is because the exam mark is not taken account of in this function)

    >>>term_work_mark(5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
    11.8
    >>>term_work_mark(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    0.0
    '''

    a0_component = contribution(a0_mark, a0_max_mark, a0_weight)
    a1_component = contribution(a1_mark, a1_max_mark, a1_weight)
    a2_component = contribution(a2_mark, a2_max_mark, a2_weight)
    ex_component = contribution(ex_mark, exercises_max_mark,exercises_weight)
    mid_component = contribution(midterm_mark, midterm_max_mark, midterm_weight)
    return (a0_component + a1_component + a2_component + ex_component + 
            mid_component)
```

As far as I understand this is basically a docstring, and in our version of a docstring it must include three things: a description, examples of what your function should do if you enter it in the python shell, and a 'type contract', a section that shows you what types you enter and what types the function will return.

Now this is all good and done, but our assignments require us to also have comments which explain the nature of our functions, using the token '#' symbol.

So, my question is, haven't I already explained what my function will do in the description section of the docstring? What's the point of adding comments if I'll essentially be telling the reader the exact same thing?

Comment: I formatted your code for you. To format code on StackExchange, just select the block of code and hit the code format `{}` button on the toolbar (or press [Cmd]+[K] or [Ctrl]+[K], depending on your prlatform).

Comment: I would argue (against whoever set your assignments) that comments are a failure to express yourself clearly in your ***code***. [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship (Robert C. Martin)](http://tinyurl.com/CleanCodeBook) is recommended reading on the matter. [Unit tests are a much better form of documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing#Documentation), in my humble opinion.

Comment: In response, I would argue that the code explains *how*, and comments explain *why*. And the docstrings are necessary to build the documentation/get help in the interpreter without looking at the implementation. But this was discussed in numerous questions here at SO, and also at Programmers.SE.

Comment: I would say that the docstring is the contract your API agrees to adhere to (primarily used by consumer of the function.)  Comments in code are more for reminders to you, about why you did something or for more contextual information for future reference (primarily used by the author of the function.)

Comment: @Bogdan, sberry: I can certainly see the benefits of docstrings (and use them conservatively in my own projects). Tests provide working code examples as to how to use an API (and will break if you break the contract, comments will not). Like you say, this has been discussed elsewhere on StackExchange.

Comment: Code comments also explain parts of the code that are not obvious, not just the "why"; sometimes the "how" is not obvious. Also, we can write comments in English that are more accurate than an implementation of those comments. Such comments help confirm that the implementation is what was required.

Answer (score 48):

It appears your teacher is a fan of How to Design Programs ;)

I'd tackle this as writing for two different audiences who won't always overlap.

First there are the docstrings; these are for people who are going to be using your code without needing or wanting to know how it works. Docstrings can be turned into actual documentation. Consider the official Python documentation - What's available in each library and how to use it, no implementation details (Unless they directly relate to use)

Secondly there are in-code comments; these are to explain what is going on to people (generally you!) who want to extend the code. These will not normally be turned into documentation as they are really about the code itself rather than usage. Now there are about as many opinions on what makes for good comments (or lack thereof) as there are programmers. My personal rules of thumb for adding comments are to explain:

- Parts of the code that are necessarily complex. (Optimisation comes to mind)
- Workarounds for code you don't have control over, that may otherwise appear illogical
- I'll admit to TODOs as well, though I try to keep that to a minimum
- Where I've made a choice of a simpler algorithm where a better performing (but more complex) option can go if performance in that section later becomes critical

Since you're coding in an academic setting, and it sounds like your lecturer is going for verbose, I'd say just roll with it. Use code comments to explain how you are doing what you say you are doing in the design recipe.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that it's worth to mention what PEP8 says, I mean, the pure concept.

## Docstrings

> Conventions for writing good documentation strings (a.k.a. "docstrings") are immortalized in PEP 257.
>
> Write docstrings for all public modules, functions, classes, and methods. Docstrings are not necessary for non-public methods, but you should have a comment that describes what the method does. This comment should appear after the def line.
>
> PEP 257 describes good docstring conventions. Note that most importantly, the """ that ends a multiline docstring should be on a line by itself, e.g.:
>
> ```
> """Return a foobang
>
> Optional plotz says to frobnicate the bizbaz first.
> """
> ```
>
> For one liner docstrings, please keep the closing """ on the same line.

## Comments

**Block comments**

> Generally apply to some (or all) code that follows them, and are indented to the same level as that code. Each line of a block comment starts with a # and a single space (unless it is indented text inside the comment).
>
> Paragraphs inside a block comment are separated by a line containing a single #.

**Inline Comments**

> Use inline comments sparingly.
>
> An inline comment is a comment on the same line as a statement. Inline comments should be separated by at least two spaces from the statement. They should start with a # and a single space.
>
> Inline comments are unnecessary and in fact distracting if they state the obvious.
>
> **Don't do this:**
>
> x = x + 1                 *# Increment x*
>
> **But sometimes, this is useful:**
>
> x = x + 1                 *# Compensate for border*

## Reference

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Answer (score 5):

First of all, for formatting your posts you can use the help options above the text area you type your post.

And about comments and doc strings, the doc string is there to explain the overall use and basic information of the methods. On the other hand comments are meant to give specific information on blocks or lines, #TODO is used to remind you what you want to do in future, definition of variables and so on. By the way, in IDLE the doc string is shown as a tool tip when you hover over the method's name.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from this page http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-docstrings/

> Python documentation strings (or docstrings) provide a convenient way
>   of associating documentation with Python modules, functions, classes,
>   and methods.
>
> An object's docsting is defined by including a string constant as the
>   first statement in the object's definition.
>
> It's specified in source code that is used, like a comment, to
>   document a specific segment of code.
>
> Unlike conventional source code comments the docstring should describe
>   what the function does, not how.
>
> All functions should have a docstring
>
> This allows the program to inspect these comments at run time, for
>   instance as an interactive help system, or as metadata.
>
> Docstrings can be accessed by the **__*doc*__** attribute on objects.

1. Docstrings can be accessed through a program  (`__doc__`) where as inline comments cannot be accessed.
2. Interactive help systems like in bpython and IPython can use docstrings to display the docsting during the development. So that you dont have to visit the program everytime.